# How to preserve margins and expand a div to fit its contents size?

Tags: html, css

I have a black rectangular header in my HTML/CSS file that must have the following behavior:

1. It must expand whenever the text inside of it requires a larger space than its minimum height, 85 pixels
2. The text inside must have a 20 pixel margin inside of the black rectangular header
3. All of the text must be visible

I am having difficulty getting it to accomplish all 3 at the same time.  It breaks horribly whenever the text inside of it becomes very large (see the Plunker link below).  Here is my HTML and CSS:

```css
.mikeproject-base-component-header .component-header .component-title .title-text span {
      font-size: 145%;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      display: inline-block;
      vertical-align: middle;
      line-height: 120%;
      font-weight: 100;
    }
    
    * {
      -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
      -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    
    .mikeproject-base-component-header .component-header .component-title .title-text {
      display: table;
      line-height: 40px;
      top: 50%;
      margin-top: -20px;
      position: absolute;
      padding-left: 20px;
    }
    
    .mikeproject-base-component-header .component-header .component-title {
      min-height:85px;
      padding: 0;
      font-family: "Open Sans";
      position: relative;
    }
    
    .portal-theme-graphite .component-header .component-title, .portal-theme-mission .component-header .component-title {
      background-color: #333333;
      border-color: none;
      color: #ffffff;
    }
    
    .mikeproject-base-component-header .component-header {
      background: white;
      font-family: "Open Sans";
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    
      <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <script src="script.js"></script>
      </head>
    
      <body>
        <div class="mikeproject-portal"><div class="par base-component base-component-header outer parbase s8 progress-container">
    <div class="inner">
    <div class="mikeproject-base-component-header portal-theme-graphite ">
      <div class="component-header">
        <div class="component-title">
          
          <div class="title-text"><span>This is a really long title This is a really long title This is a really long title This is a really long title This is a really long title This is a really long title This is a really long title</span></div>
        </div>
        
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    
    </html>
```

Finally, here is this question's plunker link:

http://plnkr.co/edit/MuynO7oSjzXcDcKOwoEo?p=preview

How do I get it to have all 3 behaviors as indicated above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fix the problem by adjusting the CSS rule for `.title-text`:

```
.mikeproject-base-component-header .component-header .component-title .title-text {
  line-height: 40px;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

You can simply use a normal block-level element with static positioning.  Use 20px to get the spacing between the edges of the block and the text. Note, you don't need absolute positioning or `display: table`.

```css
.mikeproject-base-component-header .component-header .component-title .title-text span {
  font-size: 145%;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 120%;
  font-weight: 100;
}
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.mikeproject-base-component-header .component-header .component-title .title-text {
  line-height: 40px;
  padding: 20px;
}
.mikeproject-base-component-header .component-header .component-title {
  min-height: 85px;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Open Sans";
  position: relative;
}
.portal-theme-graphite .component-header .component-title,
.portal-theme-mission .component-header .component-title {
  background-color: #333333;
  border-color: none;
  color: #ffffff;
}
.mikeproject-base-component-header .component-header {
  background: white;
  font-family: "Open Sans";
}
```

```html
<div class="mikeproject-portal">
  <div class="par base-component base-component-header outer parbase s8 progress-container">
    <div class="inner">
      <div class="mikeproject-base-component-header portal-theme-graphite ">
        <div class="component-header">
          <div class="component-title">
            <div class="title-text"><span>This is a really long title This is a really long title This is a really long title This is a really long title This is a really long title This is a really long title This is a really long title</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This looks like it's doing what I need it to do.  Thank you!

Comment: `.title-text` isn't positioned as absolute, as the asker wanted it to be (for what-ever reason).

Answer (score 3):

Why not simply use padding on the container?

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  min-height: 85px;
  background: tomato;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>This is a really long title This is a really long title This is a really long title This is a really long title This is a really long title This is a really long title This is a really long title This is a really long title This is a really long title This is a really long title This is a really long title This is a really long title</span>
</div>
<hr>
<div>
  <span>This is text</span>
</div>
```

Comment: This could work.  Are you talking about the title-text css class?  If so, I can't set the padding on it as you have indicated since its position is set to absolute (and must stay that way).

Comment: @idungotnosn - why should it remain absolutely positioned?

Comment: padding on the container is a better solution, but it still breaks when position absolute is applied as position absolute takes the element out of the flow and therefore unable to adhere to the dimensions of it's parent, please let me know what the reason is and I'll see if there's some way of maintaining those requirements :-)

Comment: @idungotnosn In that case it sounds like you have a separate, a bit bigger problem.

Comment: @idungotnosn If you add the top nav bar components to the problem statement, then we can figure out a solution.

Comment: @Nit, I believe that you are right.  I think I'm going to have to refactor the css on the page so that it doesn't rely on absolutes.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
height: auto !important; 
overflow: auto !important;
```

Comment: Do I put this in the title-text css definition?  It didn't appear to work.

Comment: !important is bad practice that should only be recommended for extreme cases, such as overriding style attributes set in HTML by js libraries over which we have no control

Answer (score 0):

you'll need to use the css class white-space:nowrap; on your span to keep it from "breaking". This way it will output itself on one continuous line.

Also, append the 20px padding to your span to achieve the required padding/margin as well as the background colour in order for the span to handle it all. Now as your text grows, your block grows.

```
.title-text{
color:#fff; 
background:#000; 
white-space:nowrap; 
padding:20px;
}
```

Example: http://plnkr.co/edit/JJfHZ9fTs0WsjZYliNXl?p=preview

Cheers!